# How do I move an element of an array of doubles in assembly language?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86-64, sse, att

I am passing an array of doubles into a function, how do I move each element into the appropriate SSE register?  How do I move a specified value into the XMM registers?  I am using AT&T syntax and the GNU assembler.

```
_variance:

    push    %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp

    xorq    %r8, %r8
    movq    %rdi, %r9
    movsd   $0, %xmm1
    movsd   $0, %xmm2
    cvtsi2sd    %r9, %xmm3
    decq    %r9
    jmp     2f
1:  movd    (%rsi, %r8, 8), %xmm0
    addsd   %xmm0, %xmm2
    mulsd   %xmm0, %xmm0
    addsd   %xmm0, %xmm1
    incq    %r8
2:  cmpq    %r8, %r9
    jl      1b
    divsd   %xmm3, %xmm1
    divsd   %xmm3,  %xmm2
    mulsd   %xmm2, %xmm2
    subsd   %xmm1, %xmm2
    movsd   %xmm2, %xmm0

    pop     %rbp
    ret
    .size   _variance,.-variance
```

Here is the C program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

variance(int n, double x[]);

int main(void) {

double array[10] = {5.5, 3.4, 7.7, 3.2, 9.1, 113.5, .125, 33.2, 93.2, .00001};
int number = 10;


double answer = variance(number, array);

printf("Variance is: %d\n", answer);

return 0;

}
```

I am calculating the variance of a range of variables.  Here is the function:

```
double sum1, sum2;
int i = 0;

while(i < n-1) {

sum1 = sum1 + (x[i] * x[i]);
sum2 = sum2 + x[i];

}

sum1 = sum1 / n;
sum2 = sum2 / n;

sum2 = sum2 * sum2;

return sum1 - sum2;
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far? If you have a specific problem and can demonstrate what you have tried (and failed at) you may be more likely to get some help on this.

Comment: Edited with code.

Comment: [MOVSD](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVSD.html) doesn't take an immediate value. It can take an XMM register or a memory operand containing a 64-bit double precision float. Simpler way to 0 out an entire XMM register is to use [PXOR](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PXOR.html) with the same register for the source and destination.

Comment: Remove the `.size   _variance,.-variance` . The syntax is wrong, and it isn't doing anything useful.

Comment: It would also help to know what the parameters are you are passing to this function and what this function is meant to do. I can take a guess, but I might be wrong. I'm assuming you are linking to a _C_ program? If you are can you show us your _C_ code as well?

Comment: I am using GNU assembler on Linux actually.

Comment: Ah okay I was curious about the underscore on `_variance`. Usually an indicator of Windows (or maybe even OS/X).

Comment: Thanks, I have to step away from the computer for a while, but I'm hoping there is enough information for someone to help you further now.

Comment: Thank you! @MichaelPetch

Comment: One observation. If you need a double precision float (64-bit) moved from memory to an XMM register you may wish to look at instruction [MOVSD](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVSD.html). You could read more than one at a time with [MOVUPD](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVUPD.html) but a starting point would be handling one double float at a time.

Comment: @MichaelPetch is right though. With the Linux/ELF ABI, there should be no leading underscore with `variance`. There are ABIs that do have a leading underscore like Mach-O (OS X).

Comment: @BrettHale I took it out and it compiled.  I think I fixed my issue but I'm having trouble linking with it now which is a seperate issue so I'm going to close this thread.